# Customizing a heatmap in R

Tags: r, visualization

I have the following code in R to create a simple heatmap.

```
data <- c(rnorm(80), rep(NA,20))
image(matrix(sample(data),nrow=50, ncol=2), las=1)
```

I want to do the following 2 things:-

1. I would like the `NA`s which are currently in white to have a diagonal red (or black) line.
2. I would like to increase the stroke width around each box in the heatmap so that each cell is clearly delineated.

How can I achieve (1) and (2)?

Comment: I strongly suspect that (1) is going to be quite difficult (in base graphics, at least).

Comment: Non-base packages are okay.

Comment: I reckon the trick to (1) will be to draw red diagonals everywhere then overplot the image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be close:

```
# fix the data because we're going to use it twice:
d=sample(data)
# plot it with X and Y coords known (note 1 larger than dimension)
image(1:51,1:3,matrix(d,nrow=50, ncol=2),las=1)
# add diagonal shading
polygon(x=c(1,51,51,1),y=c(1,1,3,3),density=3,col="red")
# replot. The NA's show through:
image(1:51,1:3,matrix(d,nrow=50, ncol=2),las=1,add=TRUE)
# outline the cells.
abline(h=1:3)
abline(v=1:51)
```

If you really want single red slashes in each box:

```
x0=c(1:50,1:50)
x1=x0+1
y0=c(rep(1,50),rep(2,50))
y1=y0+1
image(1:51,1:3,matrix(d,nrow=50, ncol=2),las=1)
segments(x0,y0,x1,y1,col="red",lwd=2)
image(1:51,1:3,matrix(d,nrow=50, ncol=2),las=1,add=TRUE)
abline(v=1:51);abline(h=1:3)
```